# What is the correct constructor method for reportlab's canvas object?

Tags: python, reportlab

I copy pasted the constructor method from the User Guide of reportlab, but it does not seem to be correct.

Error:

```
encrypt = None
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Constructor method:

```
def __init__(self,filename,
    pagesize=letter,
    bottomup = 1,
    pageCompression=0,
    encoding=rl_config.defaultEncoding,
    verbosity=0
    encrypt=None):
```

The full code (fixed with addition of comma):

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter

class PDF_Hello:
    def hello(c):
        c.drawString(100, 100, "Hello World")

    def __init__(self, filename,
                 pagesize=letter,
                 bottomup=1,
                 pageCompression=0,
                 encoding=rl_config.defaultEncoding,
                 verbosity=0,
                 encrypt = None):
        c = canvas.Canvas("hello.pdf")

PDF_object = PDF_Hello("Hello_world.pdf")
PDF_object.hello(c)
c.showPage()
c.save()
```

Update (after adding the comma on the typographical error in the User Guide of reportlab):

I encounter a `NameError: name 'rl_config' is not defined` in the default value of the `encoding` parameter--which should be working by default.

Comment: The example is missing a comma on the `verbosity=0` line.

Comment: @user2357112 Yes I noticed that, but the documentation and several websites don't have a comma for some reason. https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/08/a-simple-step-by-step-reportlab-tutorial/ and https://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf

Comment: The "some reason" is that they made a mistake. Put in the comma. (I did actually look up the user guide and check the example before making that first comment.)

Comment: Another issue i'm having is `NameError: name 'rl_config' is not defined` after adding the comma. It is on the `encoding` parameter of the constructor method. Why is this so? I believe the default value should be working as it is

Comment: you can't call the constructor field like that with PDF_object.hello(c), so it is not the full code

Answer (score 1):

*All* parameters in a function have to be separated by commas (`,`). As already mentioned in the comments, there is a `,` missing to separate your parameters in your `__init__()` method.

Your `__init__()` method should look like this:

```
def __init__(self, filename, pagesize=letter, bottomup=1, pageCompression=0,
    encoding=rl_config.defaultEncoding, verbosity=0, encrypt=None):
```

As you can see: Now, there is comma between `verbosity` and `encrypt`.

More from the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions):

> parameter_list ::=  defparameter ("," defparameter)* [","
>   [parameter_list_starargs]] | parameter_list_starargs

Here you can see, that a **","** (comma) is needed to separate parameters.